# How to non-dimensionalize this system?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider
$$
u_t=\Delta u,~~~v_t=d\Delta v.
$$
I would like to non-dimensionalize this system.
How would this be done?

For the second equation, I suggest
$$
x=\eta x_0,~~v=\gamma v_0,~~t=\frac{x_0^2\tau}{d}.
$$
Does this fit to the units? I am not sure what are the units here... its a general diffusion model...

Anyhow, I then get, for the second equation,
$$
\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial\tau}=\frac{\partial^2\gamma}{\partial\eta^2}.
$$

And how to non-dimensionalize the first equation? Or do I have to non-dimensionalise it at all?

Comment: What are independent variables in this problem?

Comment: I think t is the independent variable.